# Why do I have to reload the page to be logged in to Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Every time I visit a Stack Exchange site like Stack Overflow, the page loads and then shows me a message that I have been logged in and that I should refresh the page.

[image: Stack Exchange page refresh]

Why can't I just be logged in right away without requiring a page reload?

Comment: This is probably okay here, but this would be appropriate for [meta.stackexchange.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com), since other SE users likely have the same question.

Comment: Note that at the time you see that banner *you have been logged in*. So you can upvote, etc. But you won't see your user bar at the top, etc.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: *[Why does Stack Exchange ask for a reload on successful automatic login?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122295/why-does-stackexchange-ask-for-a-reload-on-successful-automatic-login/122300#122300)*

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This [has been answered before on Meta Stack Exchange by Kevin Montrose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122300/237685):

> Global login uses HTML5 localStorage (under the stackauth.com domain)
> to work around cookies not being available*. As a consequence, this
> means that we can't recognize a user at page render time; we have to
> wait for a non-trivial amount of javascript to load and execute.
>
> Once global login has finished, we've got the user information... but
> the user could already be interacting with the page; a hard refresh
> would be really unpleasant. We actually tried this in the very early
> days of the global log system; if you've got a really speedy
> connection** it's ok, but any sort of latency results in a UX that
> makes you want to punch your screen.
>
> **We can't attach a cookie on askubuntu.com from stackoverflow.com, nor can we access stackoverflow.com's cookies from askubuntu.com; as an example. This is the crux of the issue. We used localStorage instead of third-party cookies (which would impose the same constraints, but be simpler to implement) because Safari has really dodgy support for third-party cookies.*
>
> ***Remember, a solid 1/2 of our user base is on a different continent than our data center. We work hard to make our code fast, but we can't do much about the speed of light.*

So yes, the main part of it is as Benjamin guesses, to make the site faster. But part of it is just the fact that Stack Exchange has multiple domains (`*.stackexchange.com`, `stackoverflow.com`, `superuser.com`, etc.), and that because of this you have to attach cookies to one of those domains, and you can't load cookies cross-domain. So they used localStorage instead to store login information, which means Javascript is needed to access it.

Comment: Go to Youtube.com, sign in. Now go to google.com or mail.google.com and you will be logged in - no need to refresh + different domains. I assume this has something to do with using accounts.google.com to authenticate. This is technically feasible.

Comment: Couldn't the top bar just be updated with JavaScript instead of showing the banner? Isn't that the only difference once you are logged in?

Comment: @user1886419 google send syou over accounts.google.com for the login and then passes the token via parameter so that the site can get the cookie

Comment: @user1886419 What about upvotes?

Comment: @njahnke please elaborate. I am only a part timer on this site

Comment: @user1886419 Just bringing up an example of something else that changes in terms of drawing the page when one is logged in. If you have upvoted a question or answer, it will display that you have. There may be many other subtle changes. At any rate, it is definitely not limited to the top bar.

Comment: @njahnke either way a pseudo refresh done in JavaScript is entirely possible

Comment: Why not refresh parts of the page that would be affected by the login? Giving a user the option to stay logged in and then making them refresh each time is a UX failure, as well.

Comment: The best example I can find of this working is in WordPress Multisite. I login to the main `domain.com` that it is installed on, then when I browse to my site hosted at `anotherdomain.com` I see the WordPress Menu Bar without having to refresh `anotherdomain.com`

Comment: @user1886419 Google bounces you to the other domain before returning you to where you were as part of the login process.

Answer (score 10):

This is all guessing but...

I imagine the number of registered users who surf Stack Overflow is considerably lower than the number of unregistered ones.

Therefore, it makes a lot of sense from an optimization perspective to initially serve content to everyone who is not already logged in and only then attempt to log in or verify that the person is not logged in.

At the point the system logged you in, you've already received the page, which means a refresh would be really bad in terms of user experience - so it shows the banner instead.

**So basically, my guess is - to serve content to the average site user as fast as possible.**

Comment: This does not answer the *why a refresh is necessary* part.