# Flag declined - We don't consider cross site meta posts duplicates

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

So if a [question posted on meta-SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256214/why-do-i-have-to-reload-the-page-to-be-logged-in-to-stack-exchange-sites) is in my opinion an rather general question for meta-SE, and has been [asked and well answered on meta-SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122295/why-does-stack-exchange-ask-for-a-reload-on-successful-automatic-login), should I flag it for Off-Topic and duplicate when the new question was just asked (without any answer)?

My flag:

> OFF topic and is a duplicate: meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122295/… – Bolu May 27 '14 at 13:21

Result:

> declined - We don't consider cross site meta posts duplicates. Also not off topic.

<strike>Edit: So why my flag was declined, where as this question is closed as duplication?</strike>

Comment: If there's a good answer on MSE, then just reference that in your answer here. No need to shuffle questions all over the place.

Comment: @Bofu possibly because this question is a duplicate of a question from *this meta site* and is therefore not a `cross site meta post`.

Comment: @Bolu the name of the question is "Close as duplicate in SE meta". You're seeing the full question name, not where the question can be found.

Comment: @NickUdell, yeah, of cause it is the name of the question!