# What happens to tumbleweed badge when question is deleted

Tags: support, badges, deleted-questions, tumbleweed-badge

I had **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966040/how-to-show-an-event-from-start-date-to-end-date-in-calendar)** which I was awarded the Tumbleweed badge. Now I see today that question was deleted by *Community User*. What happens to the awarded Tumbleweed badge? Will it be gone/removed from my badge list? Or do I get to keep it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a cross-site duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work

Comment: @dfeuer You shouldn't close questions as duplicates of posts on MSE. [Shog has even said as much, just reference the answer to that in the answer here.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284789/flag-declined-we-dont-consider-cross-site-meta-posts-duplicates#comment148829_284789)

Comment: Man... and I just VTC this.....Thanks Kendra

Comment: @Kendra, okay. Weird, but okay.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

From the [badges FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17854/244519) on meta.SE

> The Stack Exchange administration has stated repeatedly that "regular" badges never go away unless they were obtained by heinous cheating.
>
> Tag badges, on the other hand, disappear immediately if you ever cease to meet their criteria, which could happen through deletion or downvotes.

So since Tumbleweed is a "regular" badge and not a tag badge, you are at no risk of losing that badge.

Comment: However you won't gain a second one unless at some point you meet the tumbleweed criteria on two non-deleted questions.

Comment: @hobbs No, it's only ever awarded once. See [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399/259693).

Answer (score 2):

The badge would remain after the question is deleted, and this is what it would look like ([example here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed?userid=6687534)):

[image: Tumbleweed on deleted question]